# Remote Debugging with GDB: Program dies after SIGILL, Illegal instruction

Tags: c, gdb

I am trying to debug code on an ARMv6-compatible processor rev 4.

I compiled the GDBserver with the `--host=arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi` flag.
The gdb itself is compiled with

```
   --host=x86_64-unknon-linux-gnu --target=arm-openwrt-linux-gnueabi --with-expat
```

If I now connect to the gdbserver in, my program is running in, I get the following error message:

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.x.x:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.x.x:2345
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
0xb6fdaec0 in ?? ()
(gdb) set sysroot /home/xxxxxx/Dokumente/lgn-sdk-v0.2/staging_dir/toolchain-arm_v6k_gcc-4.6-linaro_eglibc-2.15_eabi/
Reading symbols from /home/xxxxxx/Dokumente/lgn-sdk-v0.2/staging_dir/toolchain-arm_v6k_gcc-4.6-linaro_eglibc-2.15_eabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3...done.
Loaded symbols for /home/xxxxxxx/Dokumente/lgn-sdk-v0.2/staging_dir/toolchain-arm_v6k_gcc-4.6-linaro_eglibc-2.15_eabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function _start,
which has no line number information.

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0xb6fe8d20 in _dl_debug_initialize () from /home/xxxxx/Dokumente/lgn-sdk-v0.2/staging_dir/toolchain-arm_v6k_gcc-4.6-linaro_eglibc-2.15_eabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3
(gdb)  
Single stepping until exit from function _dl_debug_initialize,
which has no line number information.

Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
```

Comment: Did you compile your own program with the correct `-march` ? It's your program that exits with illegal instruction, not the gdb.

Comment: Yes, i thinks so.
I use the `-march=armv6k` flag in my makefile.

Comment: Does your programm also get killed if you run it without gdbserver?

Comment: No, the programm works very well without the gdbserver. Its only a small Hello World examlple to test the gdb.

`#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>



int main(int arc, char* argv[]){

 printf("anfang \n");

 printf("ende \n"); 

}`

Comment: So, do you link in your gdbserver into your binary? Or do you start it with `gdbserver yourbinary`?

Comment: I start the gdbserver with `gdbserver host:2345 hello-world`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but I have a similar problem and work around it by:

- connect via target remote
- break main
- continue
- then, set sysroot

This lets me get past the crash.  I'd certainly be interested in a better solution, though.